# iOS NSDateformatter issue - dateFromString does not work properly as expected

Tags: ios

The following snippet will give an unexpected output:

## Snippet:

```
    NSString* testDateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"2010-04-04 19:11:11"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"'%@'", testDateStr);
    NSLog(@"'%@'", [dateFormatter dateFromString:testDateStr]);
```

## Output:

> > **'2010-04-04 19:11:11'**
> >
> > **'2010-04-04 09:11:11 +0000'**

Notice the time hour in date produced is wrong. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In which local timezone are you doing the parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDateFormatter defaults to the local timezone. When you print the `description` of the NSDate object, it prints in GMT (notice the +0000 at the end). This code is working exactly as expected. (19:11:11 in your local timezone is the same as 09:11:11 in GMT.)

You can always override the timezone of the NSDateFormatter by calling `setTimeZone:`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not wrong: It looks like you are running in a locale with a GMT + 10 timezone. 19:11:11 in your local timezone is equivalent to 09:11:11 GMT (+0000)